# How do I refresh dns when my host file changes at run time?

Tags: c#, .net, dns

My tool actually rewrites the host file based on a few options and those values are used to do things like communicate with one of several databases via dns, but the problem is that in a different area of the tool, I need to use the current value of the host file. Unfortunately, it seems that the values that are present when the app is first run are all that get used.

I've tried flushing dns, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. The methods I've tried are:

- Setting timeout

`ServicePointManager.DnsRefreshTimeout = 0`  this actually broke everything. I wasn't able to communicate with the database at all.

- Importing

  ```
  [DllImport("dnsapi.dll",EntryPoint="DnsFlushResolverCache")]
  private static extern UInt32 DnsFlushResolverCache ();
  ```

This didn't seem to have any effect.

How do I ensure that my application is using the current values of my host file?

UPDATE: To be clear, I am not reading the host file in order to use it. The IPs get changed, but the app uses the host name when trying connect to the database. e.g.:

- `127.1.1.14 MyDatabase`   is in the host file, the app tries to talk to `MyDatabase`
- App changes the host file to read `127.1.1.16 MyDatabase`, the app tries to talk to `MyDatabase`, but it should resolve to .16, but instead it still resolves to .14

This seems to only affect the app which makes me think that it's caching the DNS the first time it resolves it (i.e. the first time it talks to the database) which is why I tried flushing the dns in the ways outlined above, without success. If I open command prompt and `ping MyDatabase -4` then I see the correct IP address resolve. I use my app to change the host file's IP address for that host, then `ping MyDatabase -4`, and it shows the correct updated IP, so like I said, I think it's the app that is caching it.

Answer (score 0):

I whipped up a quick console application and I didn't seem to be able to reproduce the problem you were seeing. As you can see below this requests the IP of google, then I leave an open ReadLine so I can modify the hosts file. Then come back and it reads it into a new variable and for me at least it pulled what was currently in the hosts file at the time. Are you maybe reading the DNS entry into the application prior to updating the hosts file and simply requesting the DNS information from that object rather than generating a new one? [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xk8y5.png)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;


namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string hostName = "google.com";
        Console.WriteLine(hostName);
        string myIP = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName).AddressList[0].ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("My IP Address is: {0}", myIP);
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Updating Host file");
        string newIP = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName).AddressList[0].ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("My IP Address is: {0}", newIP);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not actually pulling back values in this way. There are things being set in the hosts file such as "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx MyDatabase" and I'm using "MyDatabase" in my connection string to the database within the app. I'm not actually trying to get the value that's being resolved, I'm just trying to ensure the hostname resolves to the current value. If I change the hosts file and then restart the app, then it picks up the changes, but I don't want to have to restart the app.